# Real analysis -interior point ,accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis

**Let** $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb R$.

If $x$ be an *interior point* of $S$, show that $x$ is accumulation point of $S$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?.

Comment: don't understand how to proceed

Comment: You did not do a single step.

Comment: What  exactly is your definition of accumulation point of set $S$? Are you working in a metric space? Is $R$ the set of real numbers here? Edit answers in your question and show what you have tried uptil now.

Comment: here R is the set of real numbers

Comment: I am new to this site. I can not use mathematical symbols .pls tell me how to write them.

Comment: Please Google "LaTeX".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since $x$ is an interior point of $S$, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the neighborhood $N(x,\varepsilon)$ centered at $x$ of radius $\varepsilon$ lies in $S$. We claim that for every $\delta > 0$, there is some $x' \neq x$ such that $x' \in N(x,\delta) \cap S$, so the proof is complete. But, since for every $0 < \delta \leq \varepsilon$, there is some $x' \neq x$ such that $x' \in N(x,\varepsilon)$, we are done.

Answer (score -3):

Proof using AC: There is $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(x - \varepsilon , x+ \varepsilon) \subset S$. Let $\varepsilon_n = \varepsilon / n$ and choose $x_n$ from $(x - \varepsilon_n , x+ \varepsilon_n)$. The sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Im sorry is there a problem with the proof?

Comment: Or why the downvote

Comment: Hey I think there are always some people doing this here for no justifiable reasons...